# copy/paste Hebrew (or Cyrillic) characters into Notepad++ or other editor

Tags: html, character-encoding, notepad++, hebrew

I have never worked with Hebrew characters before, but now I have an asp (or html) and need simply copy/paste some Hebrew sentence into my html. I am using notepad++ for it.
Currently all existing Hebrew text in given file looks like this:

```
<title>&#1492;&#1506;...</title>
```

or

```
<p align="right" dir="RTL">&#1488;&#1504;&#1493; ...</p>
```

So unicode numbers are shown.

**So the problem is following:**

I am having a sentence in Hebrew in my email. I need to put it into HTML. If I do copy/paste into notepad++, I got ???? instead of characters or numbers.
How to do this? Maybe I need somehow to convert existing Hebrew sentence into unicode numbers?

I am using Notepad++, but maybe there are other editors to deal with this.

**EDIT (SOLVED my problem):**
I have found the following tool: http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html
I can copy there a text and it converts to Unicode numbers, then I can copy it to Notepad++.

Comment: Do you want to write a utility that does this or are you just looking for some online converter that will do it for you?

Comment: I need to know how to copy Hebrew charcters into notepad++ from another source (like email). I do not need any utility. I just cannot create HTMl file with given information, because all characters I am copying become ???

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes need it the other way around for Cyrillic script and I use N++'s [HTML Tag plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/).

After installing the plugin, in N++ select your text (without tags, otherwise it will encode them too), go to Plugins | HTML Tag | Encode Entities or press Ctrl+E.

Also make sure that N++'s encoding is set to UTF-8 (in Encoding | Encode in UTF-8).

Comment: Seems that your suggestion works if Hebrew text (or Cyrillic) is already in Notepad++. But I have this text in my email and when I copying it into Notepad++ I am having ????? instead of characters.

Comment: It might be N++'s encoding of the current file. Try opening a new file, first change the encoding to UTF-8 and then paste the text. The other way around won't work; once it's all ???? you can't convert it back.
Also: do you use a Unicode version of N++ ?

Comment: In the ? menu, About Notepad++. Or press F1. On the top it says Notepad++ vX.Y (UNICODE) or (ANSI). I think the Ansi version is no longer maintained. 6.0 or later are probably all Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

As funny as it is, plain Windows' Notepad is often more stable with regards to Unicode. As long as you save your file as UTF-8, you won't see surprises with question marks, character numbers, and other strange stuff. Notepad++ can support Unicode, but sometimes it has surprises.

If you need an online converter for character numbers, my favorite is
http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (I have the same problem with Hebrew characters in old VB6 programs): 
(Worked with VB6->Notepad @ Windows 10):

1. Open new notepad (now you have an empty file)
2. Click Save with Unicode encoding. <- Critical step
3. Copy what you need from your source editor (VB6 or other)
4. Paste it into good old notepad
5. Save your work (Yet another critical step :) )

Voila!